# Verification of $\forall x \in \mathbb{R},(\bigg \lfloor \frac{\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor}{2} \bigg \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{x}{4} \rfloor )$

Tags: solution-verification

## Question

This question was answered elsewhere, but I found the answer unsatisfying, mostly due to the amount of steps skipped.  Maybe I've over complicated things, but just wondering if I'm going about things correctly.

To Prove $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \left(\bigg \lfloor \frac{\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor}{2} \bigg \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{x}{4} \rfloor \right)$

*Note: For brevity I've used the following Theorem from the textbook (Epp p. 195) without proof (although it is proven in the text)*.

### Theorem 4.5.2 The Floor of $\frac{n}{2}$:

$$
    \bigg \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \bigg \rfloor = 
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{n}{2}     & \quad \text{if } n \text{ is even} \\
        \frac{n - 1}{2} & \quad \text{if } n \text{ is odd} 
    \end{cases}
$$

*Proof.* Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Let $n = \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor $.  Then by definition of floor

$$
n \leq \frac{x}{2} < n + 1.
$$

Dividing by 2 we get

$$
\frac{n}{2} \leq \frac{x}{4} < \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}
$$

This means $\lfloor \frac{x}{4} \rfloor = \frac{n}{2}$ by definition of floor.  We now consider two cases.

**Case 1.** $n$ is even.  This means $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor = \frac{n}{2}$ by Theorem 4.5.2.  But we've
shown that $\lfloor \frac{x}{4} \rfloor = \frac{n}{2}$.  Therefore,

$$\bigg \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \bigg \rfloor = \frac{n}{2} = \bigg \lfloor \frac{x}{4} \bigg \rfloor$$

Since $n = \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor$, by substitution

$$
\bigg \lfloor \frac{\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor}{2} \bigg \rfloor = \bigg \lfloor \frac{x}{4} \bigg \rfloor
$$

**Case 2.** $n$ is odd.  This means $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor = \frac{n - 1}{2}$ by Theorem 4.5.2.  Since
$n = \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor$ then by definition of floor

$$
n \leq \frac{x}{2} < n + 1
$$

Dividing by 2,

$$
\frac{n}{2} \leq \frac{x}{4} < \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}
$$

Note that $\frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{n}{2} < \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$.  Therefore,

$$
\frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{n}{2} \leq \frac{x}{4} < \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}
$$

Or by transitivity,

$$
\frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{x}{4} < \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}
$$

But this means $\lfloor \frac{x}{4} \rfloor = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{n - 1}{2}$ by definition of floor.  Since
$\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor = \frac{n - 1}{2}$ we have

\begin{align*}
    \bigg \lfloor \frac{x}{4} \bigg \rfloor &= \frac{n - 1}{2}                                                      &\\
                                            &= \bigg \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \bigg \rfloor                              &\\
                                            &= \bigg \lfloor \frac{\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor}{2} \bigg \rfloor    & \text{By substitution of } n = \bigg \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \bigg \rfloor
\end{align*}

Since we've exhausted all cases, we've shown $\bigg \lfloor \frac{\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor}{2} \bigg \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{x}{4} \rfloor$
for all real numbers as was to be shown.

Comment: The typography suggests that the line that starts with *Proof* is a proof of Theorem 4.5.2 instead of a proof of what you are arguing. I would unbold the line and shrink the font.  The statement that $\lfloor \frac x4 \rfloor =\frac n2$ is incorrect.  If $n$ is odd, $\frac n2$ is not an integer.  This turns out not to be a problem in the way you do Case 2.